# Why do I get abysmal differences in execution time in a Python regression analysis?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, google-colaboratory

When I use Lasso from sklearn.linear_model the computation times are in the vecinity of 5 - 10 seconds (even using alpha = 0, which is equivalent to OLS). However, if I try and use the function LinearRegression from the same package, it takes over 20 minutes!

Here is the code (will provide more context if interested):

These are the packages that may be needed (redundancy is likely):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.image import imread
import scipy.fftpack as spfft
from   scipy.fft import fft, dct
 
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
from skimage import io
from PIL import Image
```

The code is trying (successfully) to reproduce [this simulation of compressed SENSE](http://www.pyrunner.com/weblog/2016/05/26/compressed-sensing-python/), but this is irrelevant to the post. The general idea is that the values of the pixels of a black and white image are the regressand ("dependent variable") in a lasso regression. The regressors are cosine values - the basis vectors in a discrete cosine transform.

```
# Loading an image that will be used as the regressand:
urls = ['https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/9312897/117540238-3e6e1600-afdc-11eb-98ec-727b8629e2a7.png']  

for url in urls:
  image = io.imread(url) 

# This part is not related to the actual question (prepares the regressors
#... and the model matrix.
X = np.mean(image,-1);
ny, nx = X.shape
k  = round(nx * ny * 0.8) # % sample
ri = np.random.choice(nx * ny, k, replace=False)
b  = X.T.flat[ri] # These are the actual pixels chosen.
b  = np.expand_dims(b, axis=1)
A  = np.kron( # outer product
   spfft.idct(np.eye(nx), norm='ortho', axis=0), 
   spfft.idct(np.eye(ny), norm='ortho', axis=0)  
    )
A  = A[ri,:]
```

First the lasso regression, which takes a minimal amount of time, even using an alpha value of 0, which is supposed to be the equivalent of an OLS:

```
# Here is the lasso regression (fast, even with an alpha = 0 (~ OLS).
lasso = Lasso(alpha=0.001)
lasso.fit(A, b)
```

The last chunk is the actual OLS with the LinearRegression() formula in the same sklearn package. If you run it, be ready to wait for over 20 minutes...

```
# The OLS is commented out because it will freeze the computer for 20 min.
coefs = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False).fit(A, b).coef_
```

Comment: The [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html) say LinReg uses SVD and Lasso uses coordinate descent.  Your matrix is pretty big so I'm guessing the SVD is taking a really long time.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I did have this gut feeling, but I am an R person, and deal with Python with apprehension. I was hoping for an answer along the lines of your comment with specifics about the lin alg routines.

Comment: The model matrix is 13,027 x 16,284.

Comment: The `np.linalg.svd(A)` on Google Colaboratory crashed after 30 minutes!!!